# Multiple Database Config in Django 1.2

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is hopefully an easy question.

I'm having some trouble understanding the documentation for the new multiple database feature in Django 1.2. Primarily, I cant seem to find an example of how you actually USE the second database in one of your models.

When I define a new class in my models.py how do I specify which database I intend on connecting to?

My settings.py contains something similar to -

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'modules',
        'USER': 'xxx',                      
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',                  
    },
    'asterisk': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'users',                     
        'USER': 'xxxx',                      
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxx',                  
    }

}
```

Edit: I was reading the documentation on routers like a dummy. If anyone else is struggling with this just make sure you read it 2 or 3 times before giving up!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yeah, it is a little bit complicated.

There are a number of ways you could implement it. Basically, you need some way of indicating which models are associated with which database.

## First option

Here's the code that I use; hope it helps.

```
from django.db import connections

class DBRouter(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models in
    the contrib.auth application"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        m = model.__module__.split('.')
        try:
            d = m[-1]
            if d in connections:
                return d
        except IndexError:
            pass
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        m = model.__module__.split('.')
        try:
            d = m[-1]
            if d in connections:
                return d
        except IndexError:
            pass
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Make sure syncdb doesn't run on anything but default"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
            return False
        elif db == 'default':
            return True
        return None
```

The way this works is I create a file with the name of the database to use that holds my models. In your case, you'd create a separate `models`-style file called `asterisk.py` that was in the same folder as the models for your app.

In your `models.py` file, you'd add

```
from asterisk import *
```

Then when you actually request a record from that model, it works something like this:

1. `records = MyModel.object.all()`
2. module for `MyModel` is `myapp.asterisk`
3. there's a connection called "asterisk" so use
   it instead of "default"

## Second Option

If you want to have per-model control of database choice, something like this would work:

```
from django.db import connections

class DBRouter(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models in
    the contrib.auth application"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if hasattr(model,'connection_name'):
            return model.connection_name
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if hasattr(model,'connection_name'):
            return model.connection_name
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if hasattr(model,'connection_name'):
            return model.connection_name
        return None
```

Then for each model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    connection_name="asterisk"
    #etc...
```

Note that I have not tested this second option.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but this was immensely helpful!

Comment: Hi, I've implemented your second option. It works great except for allow_syncdb. I'll post an answer below with a working allow_syncdb for any future searchers.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was having a dickens of a time trying to grok this from the django docs.

Answer (score 8):

An addendum to Jordans answer above. For the second option, the allow_syncdb method works correctly as follows:

```
def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
    if hasattr(model,'connection_name'):
        return model.connection_name == db
    return db == 'default'
```

Comment: Interesting! So you're setting connection_name in the model?

Comment: Yes. And it works rather well except for ManyToMany fields where I have to specify a 'through' model otherwise Django generates the 'through' table in the default database.

Comment: Wow! I will definitely make a mental note of this. Good work Rich.

Answer (score 3):

Does the documentation on [automatic database routing](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) and [manually selecting a database](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database) not help?

Comment: I may be missing something but as far as I can tell there are no examples of how to define a model with anything besides the default database.

Comment: +1. Django has good documentation and the docs are almost always the first place to look.

Comment: "Django has good documentation?"  I have not found this to be the case very often.  Typically when I need to understand something I end up looking at the source code, either hosted locally or on http://djangoapi.quamquam.org/trunk/